# Grok Python Word counter

Tags: python

I need help for this program in grok python called word counter.I've looked and there has been a question asked for this specific problem but one of the answers did no work this is my programme.

```
all = []

count = {}

line = input("Enter line: ")

while line:

    word = line.split()

    line = input("Enter line: ")

for w in word:

    count[w] = count.get(w, 0) + 1

for word in sorted(count):

    print(word, count[word])
```

this is whats suppose to occur.

```
Enter line: which witch

Enter line: is which

Enter line: 

is 1

which 2

witch 1
```

but when I enter the lines this occurs

```
Enter line: which witch

Enter line: is which

Enter line: 

is 1

which 1
```

please help.

Comment: You're overwriting your `word` list (i.e. `word = line.split()`) on each new line. Did you mean to add that list to the `all` list (btw. you should not shadow built-in functions like `all`, use more creative/unique names for your variables) and then iterate over it afterwards?

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this:

```
all = []
count = {}
word = []
line = input("Enter line: ")
while line:
    word.extend(line.split())
    line = input("Enter line: ")
for w in word:
    count[w] = count.get(w, 0) + 1
for word in sorted(count):
    print(word, count[word])
```

Following the comment of [@zwer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7553525/zwer), I just created a list called "word" and added words from the lines to it using [extend](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_extend.htm)

Rest of the code remains the same.

Comment: Thank you @NitinPawar this helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert `for w in word` inside the while loop, its working for me

```
 while line:
    word = line.split()
    line = input("Enter line: ")
        for w in word:
             count[w] = count.get(w, 0) + 1
```